# VueJS : Routing confusion

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs2, vue-router

probably a stupid question especially as I am not sure if I am using VueJS or VueJS 2.0 but I am trying to get simple routing working where I can pick up the parameters / the path of the URL.

For example http://127.0.0.1/search/*****

Here is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: App },
  { path: 'search/:id', name: 'Search', component: App }
];


const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)

})
```

And on my App.component I am trying to get the :id

```
created: function() {
    //this.filterTutorials();

    this.searchTerm = this.$route.query.id;

    if (this.searchTerm == null) {
      this.searchTerm = this.$route.params.id;
    }

    console.log(this.searchTerm)
  }
```

**UPDATE**
App and search were the same component but I have not split them out (same directory)

New main.js.  It is not even calling the search page

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/App'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Home', component: App },
  { path: '/search/:id', name: 'Search', component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ './components/Search.vue'), props: true }
];


const router = new VueRouter({ mode: 'history', routes: routes });
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)

})
```

I have also updated webpacks

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `App` is statically created before the route even resolves, so the `created` lifecycle hook would check for route parameter before it even existed (i.e., it would be `undefined`). I noticed both `/search` and `/` point to `App`, but you probably meant a component name like `Search`.

You can either dynamically import `Search`:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/search/:id',
    name: 'Search',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ './views/Search.vue')
  }
]
```

Or you could use VueRouter's [`props: true`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) to automatically set `Search`'s `id` prop on navigation, obviating the check for the route parameters from `created()`.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/search/:id',
    name: 'Search',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "search" */ './views/Search.vue'),
    props: true,
  }
]
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zr1x3nlzl4)

Comment: I tried this, see updated answer and it sadly didnt even load the Search component

Comment: See [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zr1x3nlzl4). Can you update the fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You sir are epic mate!

Comment: @Burf2000 No problem :)